# The results of sha1 encryption are different between python and java

Tags: java, python, encryption, sha1

An application, i need sha1 encryption,but the results are different between python and java, java is correct.
Because there is no byte object in python, and java byte is used for hash calculation.
How to get the correct results with python?

Comment: How are you currently performing the encryption? What libraries (if any) are you using for Java and Python? Are you trying to combine both in your application?

Comment: Are you saying this doesn't work? - import hashlib
m = hashlib.sha1()
m.update("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
print(m.hexdigest())

Comment: Could you please provide the code snippet you use for this calculation? Details are needed for analysis.

Comment: In python i wrote like this : import hashlib m = hashlib.sha1() m.update("123456") print(m.digest())     In JAVA i wrote like this:import java.security.MessageDigest   MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance('SHA') md.update('123456'.getBytes('UTF-8')) println new String(md.digest())    the resaults are different

Answer (score 3):

As usual, the difference is **not** in the digest implementation (those are well-documented and implemented correctly in all major libraries). The difference is in how you *represent* the resulting data.

`md.digest()` returns a `byte[]` with the binary data produced by the digest.

`new String(md.digest())` tries to interpret those bytes as text in the platform default encoding which is *almost certainly* not what you want.

You *probably* want the digest to be represented in a hex- or Base64 encoding.

Try this (make sure to import [`javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html)):

```
String result = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(md.digest());
```

Alternatively, if you need Base64, use `printBase65Binary()` instead.

Comment: In python i do this    for i in bytearray(m.digest()):print i    then,i got [124,74,141,9,202,55,98,175,97,229,149,32,148,61,194,100,148,248,148,27]    but in java i got [124,74,-17,-65,-67,9,-17,-65,-67,55,98,-17,-65,-67,97,-17,-65,-67,32,-17,-65,-67,61,-17,-65,-67,100,-17,-65,-67,-17,-65,-67]  both m.update is (bytearray('123456'.encode('utf8'))) is it affect the results